# Can a sequence of blowups be written as one blowup with multiple exceptional divisors (and vice versa)?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry, blowup

Consider this example:
I have 3 divisors $D_1, D_2, D_3$ in a variety $X$, let's say for simplicity that they have simple normal crossing.  Now let's say I blow up the intersection $Z_1 = D_2 \cap D_3$, and denote my new variety by $X'$ with blow up morphism $\pi: X' \rightarrow X$. In the next step, I could do the "same" thing and blow up the intersection of the strict transforms $Z'_3 = D'_1 \cap D'_2$, denote this new space by $X''$.
WHat if I want to get from $X$ to $X''$ "directly? Is there a blowup which would describe $X'' \rightarrow X$ ?
Vice versa, if i have a blow up with multiple exceptional divisors, can I replace that by a sequence of blowups?

I have been sketching the dual complexes of these divisors (imagine 3 coordinate planes) and from my sketches, I cannot see the relationship between the simultaneos and sequence of blowups, but maybe I am wrong?

Comment: Isn't that just blowing up $(D_1\cap D_2)\cup(D_2\cap D_3)$?

Comment: Any projective birational morphism is the blowup of an appropriate ideal sheaf.

Comment: @user10354138: I guess I agree with you to this point, but what if I blow up $(D_1 \cap D_2) \cup (D_2 \cap D_3) \cup (D_1 \cup D_3)$ ? Like I said in the question, I am looking at the dual complexes: the dual complex for $X$ looks just like a triangle where the 3 vertices correspond to the 3 divisors. Blowing up the three intersections simultaneously results in a subdivision which now consists of 4 "inner" triangles", where as if I start with $(D_2 \cap D_3)$, the complex for $X'$ has a "line in the middle of the triangle", which will not vanish with further blowups...I think?